# Dynamically updating h1 element with another form element's textarea value

Tags: javascript, dom

I can dynamically replace the value of an `h1` element with the value of a `textarea` that is on the same html page. However, once I place several forms on the page, the h1 tag on one form, and place the textarea on another, nothing happens when I try to update the h1 value with the textarea value using ONLY plain Javascript.

I have tried `getElementById`, `getElementByTagName`, `innerHTML` and `setAttribute` to no avail. Is this impossible or I am missing something? I cannot find a single example on the web that addresses this.

UPDATE:

```
  <form id=form1 action="">
    <h1 id="h1tag">I'm H1</h1>
  </form>

  <form>
   <label for='text1'>Change H1:</label>
   <input type="textarea" value="" id="text1"/>
   <button onclick="newHeading();">newHeading()</button>
  </form>
```

The external javascript:
      function newHeading()
      {
       document.getElementById(h1tag).innerHTML = document.getElementById(text1).value;
      }

Comment: Post your code.  What you are talking about is entirely possible, but no one can help you without seeing what the issue is in your current code.

Comment: Added the code Nathan. Hope it makes sense. JS newbie.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a simple `function` with the proper `ID`'s

```
function updateH1(ta,h1) {
    var textArea=document.getElementById(ta),header=document.getElementById(h1);
    if(textArea.value) {
        header.innerHTML=textArea.value;
    }
    else {
        textArea.focus();
    }
}
```

Then use it in your `form` with the `onsubmit()` set to `return false`:

```
<h1 id="test_h1">This will change</h1>
<form onsubmit="return false;">
    <label for="text1">Change H1:</label>
    <input type="text" value="" id="text1"/>
    <button onclick="updateH1('text1','test_h1');">updateH1()</button>
</form>
```

Comment: I just tried this 'faino but no luck.Can you have a look at my code above and tell me what I am doing wrong. Thanks.

Comment: You need to have `return false` on the form for your script to run without reloading the page; check my answer for the working script.

Comment: Finally! Thanks @faino! I was at my wits end there. Thanks a lot.